# asynchronous operation/tasks in WP7/Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

When the app loads I would like to read a local resource file parse it and populate the data structure and then the UI.  I would like this happen in non-UI thread and how do I achieve this ?
The file is in Json format and I am using  json.net library to deserialize it. 
When I tested this even the progress bar is not displayed for this duration and I tried using the toolkit:performanceprogressbar and even that does not show me the progress bar so I am wondering what would be the right solution.

```
var resource = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(string.Format("testProj;component/{0}", fileName), UriKind.Relative));
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(resource.Stream);
        string jsonText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        jsonList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ComicItem>>(jsonText);
```

Answer (score 8):

The class you need is the `BackgroundwWorker` class.  You use it like this:-

```
var bw = new BackgroundWorker()
bw.DoWork += (s, args) =>
{
     // This runs on a background thread.

     var resource = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(string.Format("testProj;component/{0}", fileName), UriKind.Relative));
     StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(resource.Stream);
     string jsonText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

     jsonList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ComicItem>>(jsonText);
     // Other stuff with data. 
};
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, args) =>
{
     // Do your UI work here this will run on the UI thread.
     // Clear progress bar.
};

// Set progress bar.

bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

BTW, are you sure you can't use the `DataContractJsonSerializer`?  The fact that you feel the need to do this in an async manner would suggest that the data is sizable and memory is at a premium on WP7.  The JSON.NET approach requires that you read the entire JSON stream into a string before you deserialise it whereas the DataContractJsonSerializer can deserializer directly off a stream.

Answer (score 0):

1. Start the performance progress bar displaying by setting IsIndeterminate to true
2. Get and load your resources using a background worker thread
3. You can only update the UI on the UI thread
4. When all done set IsIndeterminate to False